# How to handle large database in Laravel application faster?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

What is the best way to process large mysql database faster in laravel application. I have a table which has round 6,00,000 records. What could be best practices to handle this data to select or query this table in optimised and faster way.

Comment: This question is very vague. Can you present a use case scenario for this?

Comment: I just wanted to know generic best practices we could have in laravel to handle large database. Like do we have to use any specific packages or any steps to follow to handle large database making your app faster.

Comment: If you set index and correct key on your column (mostly for the one you search on), it should be ok. After that, just don't load all your rows in one call and it should be fine.
In some case, you may use system like Elasticsearch or to use mysql view or denormalization (I prefer using denormalization instead of view)

Comment: That's really not that big, however u should considering eager loading, or some sort of caching, handling that much records wont hurt the stability of the website, but will hurt performance, especially if you run a lot of querys.

Comment: I have a scenario where I have to render 6 graphs ( Highcharts ) on my home page where each graph is consolidated representation hitting 6 Lakh records based on a different scenario for given time period of 2 dates. I see the page is taking more than 1 Min to load. Any suggestions to improve this performance.

Comment: Is there a concrete question here? If you want a generic answer it's write sensible code, queries and DB structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to retrieve a specific row or set of rows. you need not to worry. It will be faster. but if you are trying to retrieve all the rows from the table and manipulate its data, its better to use `chunk`

```
Model::chunk(100, function ($chunked_results) {
   //do your work here
});
```

This will retrieve 100 rows each time and pass them to the callback function.

if you have relations with them, it is better to eager load them as

```
Model::with('relations')->chunk(100, function ($chunked_results) {
   //do your work here
});
```

see [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#chunking-results)