# How can I manage a database?

Tags: android, database, laravel, user-interface

**Android app with Database Management**

I am newly user in laravel, so I have a problem about managing a huge database. We are developing an Android app. However I don't know about android app developing. I'm connected with only backend developing.

Imagine that it has main title like that "Education, News, Comedy .." etc. It calls get all query from database, then it can load all videos regarding that relevant title. I have used foreign key to do it. However when it calls education, It will pass all videos regarding that title... Imagine that you have 1000 videos about it, now How can I manage it , because I feel that it may be bad app, when it loading 1000 videos at one time. so I would be grateful to you , If you could help me..

How can I load videos for Android app using huge database? Can I apply pagination?

Comment: In case of big database I would always use pagination. And videos aren't stored in the database just the url or a reference to the video on the server so you just return url's to the video resource which could be used to embedd a video in an android app.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the number of results shown on a page, you can use the build-in pagination Laravel has (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination).

If you want to limit the number of results you get from the database with Laravel/Eloquent, you can use `limit(...)` like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->offset(10)
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

With offset, you can specify how many results you want to skip before selecting the first 5 results.

I don't know how Laravel handles large databases, but according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157357/how-to-handle-large-database-in-laravel-application-faster) it shouldn't be a problem.